# windows phone xna framework 4.0

Tags: xna, windows-phone

I am trying to run a image in xna 4.0 game by using textures as

```
Texture2D texture = Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("image1");
```

but my image during runtime is becoming stretched all other code is running quite gud but the image is becoming blurred and stretched

why is this happening and please provide the remedy?

Comment: Please specify the code you're using to display this texture, and also specify its dimensions!

Answer (score 0):

Show us code (especially method where you are loading your texture). Also if possible, show `protected override void LoadContent()` method, otherwise we will not be able to help you.